# Check exhaustiveness of types in array in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I'm making a `match` function that I'd like to be exhaustive at compile time. I know I can add a default case to ameliorate this, I'm just curious though as I've seen some wild dependent typing tricks. It would be cool if it could enforce that cases aren't duplicates either.

The an example function is

```ts
function match<T, U>(getkey: (v: T) => U, cases: Array<[U, (v: T) => T]): (v: T) => T {
  return (v) => {
      const key = getkey(v);
      const b = cases.find(([k, _]) => k == key);
      if (b) {
         return b[1](v];
      }
      throw new Error("Hit unreacheable code");
  }
}
```

Can I enforce that the cases contain all variants of `U`. It's okay to change the function parameters.

Comment: What does "all variants of `U`" mean?  Is `U` supposed to be a union or literals or something?  If so you might want to constrain it somehow in the example code.  Right now I could make `getkey` return an object type or something

Comment: Like, *maaaybe* [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLXbam) is what you're looking for?  But I'd need to see some nice use cases demonstrated as an [mre] via an [edit], before I'd begin to wade into this further.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, U is a union.

Comment: I meant to ask: is `U` supposed to be a union *of* literals (not "or" literals).  Could you answer the rest of my questions? Thanks

Comment: @jcalz Sorry for the very late reply, `U` is indeed a union *of* literals. As an update though I noticed that the lit framework implements their very similar function `choose` in a naive way, but it still gives me some light type hints from the LSP, so that should suffice, the solution above looks good too if I find time to tweak it. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that use a factory to build the matcher and enforcing rules at build time, it may be suitable for your case if such a rewrite is OK.

```
interface IMatcherFactoryEnd<Item> {
    getMatcher: () => (v: Item) => Item;
};

interface IMatcherFactory<Item, Keys, CheckedKeys extends Keys> {
    when: <K extends Exclude<Keys, CheckedKeys>>(
        key: K,
        fn: (v: Item) => Item,
    ) => (Exclude<Keys, CheckedKeys | K> extends never ? IMatcherFactoryEnd<Item> : IMatcherFactory<Item, Keys, CheckedKeys | K>);
};

class MatcherFactory<Item, Keys, CheckedKeys extends Keys>
implements
    IMatcherFactory<Item, Keys, CheckedKeys>,
    IMatcherFactoryEnd<Item>
{
    constructor (
        private getkey: (v: Item) => Keys,
        private cases: [CheckedKeys, (v: Item) => Item][],
    ) { }

    when <K extends Exclude<Keys, CheckedKeys>>(
        key: K,
        fn: (v: Item) => Item,
    ) {
        return new MatcherFactory<Item, Keys, CheckedKeys | K>(
            this.getkey,
            [...this.cases, [key, fn]],
        );
    }

    getMatcher () {
        const getkey = this.getkey;
        const cases = this.cases;
        return (v: Item) => {
            const key = getkey(v);
            const b = cases.find(([k, _]) => k === key);
            if (b) return b[1](v);
            throw new Error("Hit unreacheable code");
        };
    }
}

export function matcherFactory <Item, Keys> (
    getkey: (v: Item) => Keys,
): IMatcherFactory<Item, Keys, never> {
    return new MatcherFactory<Item, Keys, never>(
        getkey,
        [],
    );
}

const getKey = (v: boolean) => v ? "true" as const : "false" as const;

export const matcher_OK = matcherFactory(getKey)
    .when("true", () => false)
    .when("false", () => true)
    .getMatcher();

export const matcher_KO1 = matcherFactory(getKey)
    .when("true", () => false)
    .getMatcher();

export const matcher_KO2 = matcherFactory(getKey)
    .when("false", () => true)
    .getMatcher();

export const matcher_KO3 = matcherFactory(getKey)
    .when("true", () => false)
    .when("false", () => true)
    .when("true", () => false)
    .getMatcher();

export const matcher_KO4 = matcherFactory(getKey)
    .when("true", () => false)
    .when("false", () => true)
    .when(true, () => false)
    .getMatcher();
```